# Selecting through text in select_list not through index

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript,

I know how to select a select_list by

```
document.getElementById("entry_1000001").selectedIndex=2
```

But Is there any way available to select through text directly something like

```
document.getElementById("entry_1000001").select("Ruby")
```

HTML Element follows

```
<select name="entry.1000001" id="entry_1000001" aria-label="What language does Watir-WebDriver use?  " aria-required="true" required=""><option value=""></option>
<option value="Java">Java</option> <option value="Ruby">Ruby</option> <option value="C#">C#</option> <option value="Clojure">Clojure</option> <option value="Python">Python</option></select>
```

Comment: Sure, `document.getElementById("entry_1000001").value = "Ruby";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
document.getElementById("entry_1000001").value = "Ruby";
```

```html
<select name="entry.1000001" id="entry_1000001">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="Java">Java</option>
  <option value="Ruby">Ruby</option>
  <option value="C#">C#</option>
  <option value="Clojure">Clojure</option>
  <option value="Python">Python</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I thought this value method is for text_field, I was not aware the fact that select_list also has this value method, thanks.

Comment: @RAJ yes, (if that option exists) it sets it under the hood as `selected`. You can easily test the above by doing later `var sel = document.getElementById("entry_1000001");
console.log(sel.options[sel.selectedIndex]);`

Comment: Okay, thank you. I have another question,If I don't have an id to the field, Can I locate using name field? ,I find only getElementsByName method. Is there any way can I locate the element  when I don't have any id and I have the name?

Comment: @RAJ yes there are several ways `document.getElementsByName("foo")[0]` where `0` is the index of your element, or by looping the retrieved collection. Newer, somewhat slower (does not matters at all) version is `document.querySelector("[name='foo']")` like [in this demo](http://jsbin.com/namavik/1/edit?html,css,js,console,output)

Comment: Pretty amazing, Thank you! I started to learn JavaScript now for embedding inside my automation scripts. Thank you.

Comment: No problem! Good luck, have fun & don't give up